# Listview with more than one Checkbox per row?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I been looking for a way to add two checkboxes per row, I'm really frustrated and need some help, do any one knows how to solve this? because I just can have a checkbox per row. I don't get why Microsoft didn't take care of this since I can think in other cases where I would need radio buttons or even combo boxes...

Answer (score -2):

This question is almost 10 Years old, but I suggest to use WPF and make a Grid with two Rows in the Listview

Comment: Change from Winforms to WPF should not be an answer. Maybe it is a big project, that already uses Winforms. He can't change the entire platform to solve a task.